# Choose ComboBox value and convert it into a int

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a ComboBox with the values 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and when I choose one of this Numbers I want to convert the choosen number into an Integer so I can use it for another function.

The code looks like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selected = this.comboBox1.GetValue(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    int N = Int32.Parse(selected.Text);
}
```

The problem is that I get an Error by `this.comboBox1.GetValue` GetValue.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Why not just `int N = Int32.Parse(this.comboBox1.Text);`?

Comment: remove .Text : int N = Int32.Parse(selected);

Comment: i get a problem with the Format exception

Comment: @Chandru still getting the same Error ....

Comment: ComboBox does not contain a method called GetValue. Your value will be in combobox1.SelectedItem

Comment: @LexWebb isn't there an easier way to just get the value out of the ComboBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value out of your ComboBox by doing

```
int N = Int32.Parse(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
 bool result = Int32.TryParse(this.combobox.text, out int n);
 if (result)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Converted number!);
    // n is now an int!
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number") 
 }
```

Comment: You can also use combobox.selecteditem instead of .text